# NPM how to configure location of global repository

Tags: node.js

Does anyone know how to configure location of global repository?

My global repo is somewhere under $HOMEDRIVE/$HOMEPATH/blahblahblah

and all my packages are being installed under that place fopr global reference

but I want to park it somewhere specific and secret like the docroot of my appserver ? so I can operate demos and proof-of-concepts and prototypes ands show them off

can you tell me how I can configure the path to my global repository? I am on windows7 which is thoroughly supported and chmod chown issues are not as prevalent on linux

is this directory anchor controlled by a designated variable within NPM?
is this variable ever referenced by javascript modules indiscriminantly? i would hope not

I assume this variable is within the NPM tool itself. 
what about bower... would bower operate the same configurable? or is bower a different animal and place.

is bower a subset of npm? anmd of so does it operate the same configuration as npm?

thank you

Answer (score 10):

See the npm docs [about the folders](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders). It states that the global modules are installed under a configured `prefix`. You can get it from the npm config comand:

```
npm config get prefix
```

And you may change it with a similar command:

```
npm config set prefix /path/to/my/global/folder
```

However, modules are usually installed globally if want to use some command line command they provide. For using in some node.js application, prefer to install them locally. If you still want to use the globally installed modules inside the application, you should use the [`link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) command (though I'm not sure if it works in a Windows environment).

Bower is another thing completely. Looking at the [api documentation](http://bower.io/docs/api/#install), you will see that there is no option to install modules globally (which makes sense, as Bower is intended for front-end dependencies).

You could change the default folder using the `directory` parameter of your `.bowerrc` file ([see the documentation](http://bower.io/docs/config/#directory)). This way you would be able to set all projects to use the same folder, but notice that's not the way it's intended to use and you would need to set it in all projects.

Answer (score 10):

```
npm config set registry <registry url>
```

once this command is run, check in `~/.npmrc`, it must show your changes.